# Fast way scaling arrays (2d matrix of ones and zeros) with a specific factor

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, matrix, scaling

I have an array (**`2d matrix of ones and zeros`**)  like below and like to change it's size and so I've developed a function you can also find below.

```
'011111'               '001111111111'
'000000'               '001111111111'
'000011'     --->      '000000000000'
'000001'               '000000001111' 
                       '000000001111'
                       '000000000011'
```

---

```
'011111'               '001111111111'
'000000'               '001111111111'
'000011'     <---      '000000000000'
'000001'               '000000001111' 
                       '000000001111'
                       '000000000011'
```

---

So the **example task** above is working fine with the code below. But scaling down a big matrix *`(2000*1000)`* to *`(40*20)`* takes a LONG time. Also in the other direction *`(40*20)`* to *`(2000*1000)`*

> So does anybody has an idea how to edit my code to make it working way faster?

So I would be very thankful if somebody shares some working code matching my problem, however.. Thanks a million in advance,

Nina.

---

```js
var matrix=[

  '011111000000000000000000001111000000000000000000000000000000000000000011111110000000000000001011',
  '001111000000000000000000011110000000000000000011111000000000000000000001111111000000000000011101',
  '001111100000000000000000111110000000000000111111111111100000000000000000011111100000000000010100',
  '011111000000000000000000111100000000000111111111111111111000000000000000000111110000000000111000',
  '000000000000000000000001111100000000001111111111111111111110000000000000000001100000000000111000',
  '000000000000000000000001111000000000111111111111111111111111000000000000000000000000000001110000',
  '000000000000000000000011110000000001111111111111111111111111100000000000000000000000000001110000',
  '000000000000000000000111110000000011111111111111111111111111111000000000000000000000000011100000',
  '000000000000000000000111100000000111111111111111111111111111111000000000000000000000000111000000',
  '000000000000000000001111100000001111111111111111111111111111111100000000000000000000000111000001',
  '000000000000000000011111000000011111111111111111111111111111111110000000000000000000001110000001',
  '000000000000000000011110000000011111111111111111111111111111111111000000000000000000001110000000',
  '000000000000000000111110000000111111111111111111111111111111111111110000000000000000000111000000',
  '000000000000000000111100000001111111111111111111111111111111111111100000000000000000011000000001',
  '000000000000000001111100000001111111111111111111111111111111111111111000000000000000001110000000',
  '000000000000000011111000000001111111111111111111111111111111111111111000000000000000011100000000',
  '000000000000000011111000000011111111111111111111111111111111111111111110000000000000001111000001',
  '000000000000000111110000000011111111111111111111111111111111111111111110000000000000011100000001',
  '000000000000001111100000000011111111111111111111111111111111111111111100000000000001110000000001',
  '000000000000001111100000000011111111111111111111111111111111111111111110000000000000011100000001',
  '000000000000011111000000000111111111111111111111111111111111111111111110000000000001110000000001',
  '000000000000011111000000000111111111111111111111111111111111111111111110000000000111000000000001',
  '000000000000111110000000000111111111111111111111111111111111111111111110000000000011000000000001',
  '000000000000111100000000000111111111111111111111111111111111111111111110000000000011000000000001',
  '000000000000111100000000000111111111111111111111111111111111111111111110000000111000000000000001',
  '000000000001111000000000000111111111111111111111111111111111111111111110000000010100000000000001',
  '000000000001111000000000000111111111111111111111111111111111111111111100011100000000000000000001',
  '000000000111110000000000000111111111111111111111111111111111111111111000001111000000000000000001',
  '000000000111100000000000000011111111111111111111111111111111111111111000000011100000000000000001',
  '000000000111100000000000000011111111111111111111111111111111111111110000001111000000000000000001',
  '000000000111100000000000000011111111111111111111111111111111111111100000000111000000000000000001',
  '000000101111110000000000000001111111111111111111111111111111111111100000000110000000000000000001',
  '000000001111111000000000000001111111111111111111111111111111111111000000111000000000000000000001',
  '000000000111111110000000000000111111111111111111111111111111111110000000011110000000000000000001',
  '000000000011111111100000000000111111111111111111111111111111111100000000011100000000000000000001',
  '000000000001111111110000000000011111111111111111111111111111111100000000111000000000000000000001',
  '000000000000011111111000000000001111111111111111111111111111111000000001111000000000000000000001',
  '000000000000001111111100000000001111111111111111111111111111110000000001110000000000000000000001',
  '000000000000000011111111000000000011111111111111111111111111100000000001110000000000000000000001',
  '000000000000000001111111110000000001111111111111111111111111000000000010000000000000000000000001',
  '000000000000000000111111111000000000111111111111111111111100000000000111100000000000000000000001',
  '000000000000000000001111111110000000001111111111111111111000000000000111000000000000000000000001',
  '000000000000000000000011111111100000000011111111111111000000000000001111000000000000000000000001',
  '000000000000000000000001111111111000000000001111111000000000000000001110000000000000000000000001',
  '000000000000000000000000011110111100000000000000000000000000000000011100000000000000000000000001'
]


Array.prototype.scale_matrix = function(scale_factor) {
 var matrix = this;
 var scale = 1 / scale_factor;
 var array = duplicate_matrix(Math.round(this.length * scale_factor), Math.round(this[0].length * scale_factor), '0').map(str => Array.from(str, String))
 if (scale_factor < 1) {
  for (var y = 0; y < array.length; y++) {
   for (var x = 0; x < array[0].length; x++) {
    _y = Math.round(y / scale_factor);
    _x = Math.round(x / scale_factor);
    var old_values = []
    for (var oldx = _x; oldx < _x + scale; oldx++) {
     for (var oldy = _y; oldy < _y + scale; oldy++) {
      try {
       old_values.push(matrix[oldy][oldx]);
      }
      catch (e) {}
     }
    }
    var new_value = old_values.sort((a, b) => old_values.filter(v => v === a).length - old_values.filter(v => v === b).length).pop();
    array[y][x] = matrix[_y][_x];
   }
  }
 }
 else {
  for (var y = 0; y < matrix.length; y++) {
   for (var x = 0; x < matrix[0].length; x++) {
    _y = Math.round(y * scale_factor);
    _x = Math.round(x * scale_factor);
    for (var newx = _x; newx < _x + scale_factor; newx++) {
     for (var newy = _y; newy < _y + scale_factor; newy++) {
      try {
       array[newy][newx] = matrix[y][x];
      }
      catch (e) {}
     }
    }
   }
  }
 }
 return array.map(a => [a.join('')]).concat.apply([], array.map(a => [a.join('')]));
}
function duplicate_matrix(rows, cols, value) {
 var arr = [];
 for (var i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
  arr.push([]);
  arr[i].push(new Array(cols));
  for (var j = 0; j < cols; j++) arr[i][j] = value;
 };
 return arr;
}


console.log(matrix.scale_matrix(0.3).join('\n'));
console.log('\n\n>------<\n\n');
console.log(matrix.scale_matrix(1.3).join('\n'));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: `var new_value = ...` is a waste; you don't use the result. By consequence also `old_values` is useless, and then the inner two loops are useless. I guess you were up to something with that, but didn't finish the implementation.

Comment: I can not really get your thoughts, so would it be possible for you to share some code trincot? Thanks in advance ❤️